# Django Grappelli usergroup conditional dashboard

Tags: django, admin, dashboard, usergroups

Working with Grappelli(2.11.1) in Django(1.11.10). 
I crafted small custom dashboard and look now for some method to variate appearance of elements.
In particular I need to show some url-element

```
self.children.append(modules.LinkList(
    _('e-mail'),
    column=2,
    css_class=('grp-collapse grp-closed'),
    children=[
        {
            'title': _('gmail'),
            'url': 'gmail.com',
            'external': True,
        },
    ]
))
```

only to users of specified group and to hide it to others.
In regular way I would try to use auth.get_user(), but this depends on 'request'. Which is not available, or at least visible, for me.
Any way to make this feature?
Thanks anyway.

Answer (score 0):

One possible workaround for this (though there are almost certainly better ways):

First, add `'django.template.context_processors.request'` to `settings.TEMPLATES['OPTIONS']['context_processors']` if it isn't there already. That'll add requests to the template context.

Next, do your changes to the custom dashboard within the init_with_context method, where you now have access to the request (and therefore request.user)

```
from grappelli.dashboard import modules, Dashboard

class CustomDashboard(Dashboard):

    def init_with_context(self, context):
      request = context['request']
      user = request.user
      groups = user.groups.all()
      if groups == "whatever condition you want":
        self.children.append(
            ...
        )
```

Comment: Yes. I got the user object in dashboard script. Thanks.